# Escaping special Tags for HTML

Tags: html, regex, perl

I'm pretty new to perl and recently wrote a converter for our SharePoint.
It basically takes our old wiki's html pages and converts them to aspx pages with SP classes and so on.

Everything works fine till the point someone used `<tags>` as Text. 
Here's an example form the html of the old twiki:

`<li> Moduldateinamen haben folgendes Format <code> <Content>_<Type>_<Name>_</code> ...`

So `<Content> <Type> <Name>` is text wrapped in a `<code>` Tag

**How it looks in old wiki:**

[image: How it looks in old wiki]

**How it looks after converting to aspx and uploaded to SharePoint:**
[image: How it looks after converting to aspx and uploaded to SharePoint]

You can see that SP tried to interpret them as tags (sure), not as text and therefore it wont be displayed.

For SharePoint Pages I need an escaped HTML markup between SP ASPX markup.
So I've changed f.e. `<` to `&lt;` and so on via regex.

However the example snippet I posted should look like this in the ASPX:

```
&lt;li&gt; Moduldateinamen haben folgendes Format &lt;code>&gt;openTagContentclosingTag_openTagTypeclosingTag_openTagNameclosingTag_&lt;/code&gt;
```

So < converts to openTag and > to closing Tag but only for actual content between this `<li>` tag. Later this needs to be changed by hand (I don't see another way)

How can I achieve that only "text" tags get escaped with openTag/closingTag but "real" HTML markup gets escape in this manner `<` to `&lt;`

Comment: Yes, this is confusing :D Why not just scrape the contents of the Wiki to get only the content you want. Use [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM). Also there are lots of modules for parsing this stuff like [Text::WikiText](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::WikiText)

Comment: What's the equivalent of the `<code></code>` markup in Sharepoint? In Markdown, it would be backticks. If you replace the things to actually do the proper markup it will not be a problem to have those. But that might cause a simple `s/</&lt/g` to make your resulting text not what you want...

Comment: SharePoint can interpret <code> but there is no control for "a normal user" to add code on button click. You need to open the source to edit it. So <code> tag is okay to be escaped and migrated from old wiki to SP. But the tags within <code> shall be escape different so they  a)  dont get interpreted b) can be changed back to <tags> in SharePoints editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled around and found a solution that *might* work. It does work with example data, but I don't know how complicated your actual documents are.

Consider this example input.

```
my $html = <<'HTML';
<ul>
    <li><code>tecdata\de\modules:</code> Testbausteine blafasel</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li> Moduldateinamen haben folgendes Format <code> <Content>_<Type>_<Name></code> (Ausnahme: <code>ti_<Name>)</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><Content> bezeichnet den semantischen Inhalt</li>
                    <li><code>ti_</code> diese ganzen Listen sind verwirrend
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<p>And more stuff here...</p>";
HTML
```

And the following program.

```
# we will save the tag-looking words here
my %non_tags;

# (8) replace html with the concatenanted result
$html = join '', map {
    my $string = $_;

    # (2) find where the end-tag is
    my $pos = index($string, '</code>');
    if ($pos >= 0) {
        # (3) take string until the end-tag
        my $escaped = substr( $string, 0, $pos );

        # (4) remember the tag-looking words
        $non_tags{$_}++ foreach $escaped =~ m/<([^>]+)>/g;

        # (5) html-escape the <>
        $escaped =~ s/</&lt;/g;
        $escaped =~ s/>/&gt;/g;

        # (6) overwrite the not-escaped part with the newly escaped string
        substr( $string, 0, $pos ) = $escaped;
    }
    $string;
} split m/(<code>)/, $html; # (1) split on <code> but also take that delimiter

# html-escape those tag-looking words all over the text
foreach my $word ( keys %non_tags) {
    $html =~ s/<($word)>/&lt;$1&gt;/g ;
}

print $html;
```

The output from that is the following.

```
<ul>
    <li><code>tecdata\de\modules:</code> Testbausteine blafasel</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li> Moduldateinamen haben folgendes Format <code> &lt;Content&gt;_&lt;Type&gt;_&lt;Name&gt;</code> (Ausnahme: <code>ti_&lt;Name&gt;)</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>&lt;Content&gt; bezeichnet den semantischen Inhalt</li>
                    <li><code>ti_</code> diese ganzen Listen sind verwirrend
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<p>And more stuff here...</p>";
```

As you can see, it html-escaped all tag-like words inside of `<code></code>` tokens. It also remembered what those words were, and then replaced further occurrences of those words that still look like tags. That way, we do not mess up actual HTML.

**This is a very naive approach**, but since this is a one-time task a crap solution that works is better than no solution.

Comment: I could almost use it without editing, but all <a> Tags got damaged. I laughed at your "diese ganzen Listen sind verwirrend". Well, our old wiki system was used in many different ways. Some used an editor, others went and edited the source, so we got a big, ugly and sometimes damaged html. I'm happy that SP can deal with that with little adjustments.

Comment: @Thomas glad it helped. Because you didn't show code I had to guess what the HTML would look like. A more complete example would have been useful. What did you change to make it work? I'm also happy you found that little joke. Not everyone reads long posts nowadays. :)

Comment: if you are interested I can upload my noob code + Wiki html + converted SP aspx. To restore the links I just wrote a regex which transforms openTagaclosingTag back to <a> and same for </a>.

Comment: Sure, drop it in a gist and add the link as a comment here. :)

Comment: [here it is](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c57c1d6d1b9db6c5c5ebde18e979282) I stripped the HTML cause of its content. I got a last problem. My $_ holds the header of the whole HTML even that I only download the content of a div (I dont need the navigation and so on, div is called patternContent) Now this gets added to my final aspx and wrecks it. If I manually delete that the aspx is just as I want it to be. Guess I need another regex to remove the content of $_ again from my $htmlContent which gets written into my aspx.

Comment: ufff, I am so blind. Missed to change a variable from your example... Your code is perfect as it is. MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question right, all you need is a regex like:

```
$page =~ s{(?<=<code>)(.+?)(?=<\/code>)}
          {
              my $text = $1;
              $text =~ s/([<>])/ $1 eq '<' ? '&lt;': '&gt;'/ge;
              $text;
          }gxe;
```

Comment: Yes sir, thats it! Thanks for that :)

Comment: That will not escape the mentions of `<Content>` where it's not marked as `<code></code>` in the bullet _<Content> bezeichnet den semantischen..._.

Comment: Yes you are right, it only works for "text"-tags in the code block but still it is working :) gonna test your other answer today